# Direct to another page while changing a class on that page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two html pages and i need to link the first page to the second and then modify a class of an element on that second page.

For example.. page one have 2 buttons if you press the first, you get directed to the second page and the second pages background becomes green. If you press the second button you get directed the same way, but the background becomes blue.

Is there a way of doing this? Not using jquery.

Comment: Redirect with a parameter appended to the URL, read and process it on the receiving page.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a parameter via the query string and use `document.location.search` on page 2 to get the parameter and set the color accordingly.

```
<a href="page2.html?color=green">Green</a>
<a href="page2.html?color=blue">Blue</a>
```

Then on page2:

```
<script>
    // Assuming the query string is ?color=blue,
    // splitting on = will result in ["?color", "blue"].
    // In the real world you shouldn't assume it's in
    // exactly that format, but for the sake of example...

    var color = window.location.search.split('=')[1];

    // add the css class 'blue' to the body tag.
    var document.body.classList.add(color);
</script>
```

And in css:

```
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you. What if i need to change multiple elements? Basically what i need is to set these divs on page2 to this:

el1.style.display = "block";
el2.style.display = "none";
el3.style.display = "none";
el4.style.display = "none";

And thats ofcourse after you press the button on page1
<a href="page2.html</a>

Comment: There a couple routes you could go. You could do it with css by using the body.blue selector to highlight the one you want and hide the others. Or you could assign a class to the divs that hides them all and then remove that class from the visible one using `document.querySelector(...).classList.remove(...)`, but it's starting to seem like you might want to do this server-side? Just render page2 the way you need it based on the parameter? Why do it client side with javascript?

Comment: Was just wondering if there were a way of doing it on the client side, since i don't any server side languages